# Fastest way to input integers

Tags: c++, c

What's the best way to get lots of small-sized integers from a user through the terminal?

The 'scanf' function isn't fast enough for what we need.

Above is in the context of participating in an ACM ICPC coding contest where code efficiency is paramount.

P.S: Stdin is basically a file

Comment: Do you mean, fastest for you to write or fastest for the user to use?

Comment: I assume he means fastest run time?

Comment: @Duck, Use `SendInput` and the like. It sends keystrokes much faster than fast humans can type ;)

Comment: A fast human would input an integer in about 1 second (at best). Your input code would take about 1 millisecond (at worst). What would you achieve by optimizing it?

Comment: For what it's worth, stdin basically is a file, so the approach is the same, though the functions may have slightly different names (scanf vs fscanf)

Comment: @Corbin : Thanks,I forgot that

Answer (score 3):

I think an approach based on `scanf` will be hard to beat.  In any case, it will be easy to implement.  So I'd start with that, if it's not sufficient, benchmark before trying anything else.

If the input consists of whitespace-separated integers:

```
scanf("%d ", &input)
```

Answer (score 0):

for continuous input processing you can try this

```
while( scanf("%d ", &val) == 1)
{
    // processing : do what you want 
}
```

also you can use this for file inputs reading (`fscanf`)